# google remarketing - Google Remarketing on custom tags list

Tags: google-ads-api

I have few web pages, which correspond to certain keywords which the user will enter on the search band of my website.

I want to put google remarketing code on some specific pages based on these keywords. I have list of 1350 combinations. How should I proceed with adding google remarketing code on these web pages?

Comment: Solved this problem. Actually this eluded and i didn't keep track of it. This was solved way before. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a Global Site-wide Google Remarketing tag to your whole site:

Instructions here 
http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2476688

"Adding your remarketing tag to your entire website"

and then

Create a remarketing list per keyword by having the keyword show in the URL.

instructions: http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2454064

Since you have many keywords I suggest checking which ones have the most traffic and start working with the top 10 and see if it brings the results you are looking for.

I do not know of a way to do create 1350 lists in bulk.